# prime $p$ different from $3$ is of the form $3k+1$ if and only if $p$ divides number of form $c^2+c+1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Prove that prime $p$ different from $3$ is of the form $3k+1$ if and only if $p$ divides number of from $c^2+c+1$

i am trying but i did't get answer any hint please

Comment: Can we use the fact that $p=3k+1$ implies $p=m^2+mn+n^2$?

Comment: @OscarLanzi..sry i dont knoq

Comment: Hmm... so you could use this then to prove there are infinitely many primes $\equiv 1 \pmod{3}$: for any finite list of such primes $p_1, \ldots, p_n$, set $c := 3 p_1 \cdots p_n$, and then any prime divisor of $c^2 + c + 1$ would have to be a prime $\equiv 1 \pmod{3}$ and not in the list.

Comment: If $c^2+c+1\equiv0$, then $c^3-1=(c-1)(c^2+c+1)\equiv0$, too. So $c$ is of order $3$. Then apply Lagrange. For the other direction use that $\Bbb{Z}_p^*$ is cyclic of order $p-1$, hence has an element of order three. Work those same congruences backwards.

Comment: @JohnWatson I am sure this is a duplicate. But I didn't find one in my first search. I may try again.

Comment: Closely related to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2467631/existence-of-integers-a-and-b-such-that-p-a2-abb2-for-p-3-or-p. @JyrkiLahtonen, is that the question you're looking for?

Comment: Also [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/15721/11619).

Answer (score 3):

Notice that if $p\equiv 1$ mod 3, then $3$ divides $p-1=\phi(p)$ where $\phi$ is the euler function. This implies that there exists $c$ not congruent to 1 mod $p$ such that $c^3\equiv 1$ mod p, (this is a fact from group theory). From this you can conclude that 
$p$ divides $c^3-1=(c-1)(c^2+c+1)$. Since $p$ doesn't divide $c-1$ you have that $c^2+c+1$.

The other direction shouldn't be that hard.

(I just noticed that this is the solution Jyrki said in the comments).

Answer (score 1):

**Solution with Legendre symbol**.

Say $p=6k+r$ where $r\in \{1,5\}$ ($r$ can't be $0,2,3$ and $4$).

\begin{eqnarray*}
p\mid c^2+c+1 &\Longleftrightarrow & p\mid (2c+1)^2+3\\
 &\Longleftrightarrow & -3\equiv_p (2c+1)^2\\
&\Longleftrightarrow & \Big({-3\over p}\Big) =1 \\
&\Longleftrightarrow & \Big({-1\over p}\Big)\cdot \Big({3\over p}\Big)=1\\
&\Longleftrightarrow & \Big({-1\over p}\Big)\cdot \Big({3\over p}\Big)=1\\
&\Longleftrightarrow & (-1)^{p-1\over 2}\cdot (-1)^{\big[{p+1\over 6} \big]}=1\\
&\Longleftrightarrow & {p-1\over 2}+ \Big[{p+1\over 6} \Big]\equiv_2 0\\
&\Longleftrightarrow & 3k+{r-1\over 2}+ k\Big[{r+1\over 6} \Big]\equiv_2 0\\
&\Longleftrightarrow & {r-1\over 2}+ \Big[{r+1\over 6} \Big]\equiv_2 0\\
&\Longleftrightarrow & r=1
\end{eqnarray*}

---

**Second solution (only one way)**

Perhaps it would be easyer to see that $$c^2+c+1 \equiv _6 1,3$$ 
Each prime that divide $c^2+c+1$ is $3$ or $6k+r$ where $r=1$ or $r=5$. 
It is easy to see that the sets $$A=\{6a+1;\;a\in \mathbb{Z}\}$$ and $$B= \{6b+5;\;b\in \mathbb{Z}\}$$
are closed for multiplication. And if we multiply $x\in A$ and $y\in B$ we get $xy\in B$.

So if there is at least one $p \equiv_6 5$, then product of all primes would be $\equiv_6 5$ but this can be.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution using Einsenstein integers**

The Eisenstein ring $E:=\mathbf Z [\omega]$ is the ring of integers of the quadratic field $\mathbf Q(\omega)$, where $\omega$ is a primitive cubic root of unity. $E$ is a PID (even a Euclidian domain) in which the decomposition of the rational primes $p$ is classically known : (i) $p=3$ is totally ramified, more precisely $3$ is associate to $(1-\omega)^2$ ; (ii) $p\equiv-1\pmod 3$ is inert, i.e. $p$ remains prime in $E$ ; (iii) $p\equiv 1\pmod 3$ is totally split, i.e. $p=\pi.\bar{\pi}$, the product of two conjugates primes of $E$. The splitting case is equivalent to $p=N(\pi)$ , where the norm $N$ is such that  $N(a+b\omega)=a^2 + b^2 - ab$ (see the hint of @Oscar Lanzi). Since $E$ is a PID, for any prime $\pi$, the quotient $E/\pi E$ is a finite field of order $N(\pi)$, and case (iii) is equivalent to saying that $\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z \cong E/\pi E$, or that $ (E/\pi E)^*$ is a cyclic group of order $N(\pi)-1=p-1$.

Now, sticking to case (iii), fix a generator $g$ of $(E/\pi E)^*$, so that $x=g^{\frac {p-1}{3}}$ is a cubic root of unity in $(E/\pi E)^*$. But $x^3 - 1= (x-1)(x-\omega)(x-\omega^2)$ in $ (E/\pi E)^*$, where the three cubic roots of unity are easily seen to be distinct. It follows that case (iii) is equivalent to saying that $g^{\frac {p-1}{3}}$ is a root of $(x-\omega)(x-\omega^2)=x^2 +x + 1$. Using the isomorphism $\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z\cong E/\pi E$, this is in turn equivalent to $c^2+c+1=0$ in $(\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z)^*$, where $c$ corresponds to $g^{\frac {p-1}{3}}$ .

Of course, the above argument appears unduly complicated compared to those of @Jose Cruz or @John Watson. But it presents the advantage to surrepticiously introduce Legendre's *symbol of cubic residues*, which can be defined as follows. In both cases (ii) and (iii), if $\pi$ is a prime of $E$ not dividing $\alpha \in E$, obviously $\alpha^{N(\pi)-1}\equiv 1\pmod \pi$. Note that $N(\pi)=p^2$ in case (ii),  so that, as previously, $\alpha^{\frac{N(\pi)-1}{3}}\equiv 1, \omega,\omega^2 \pmod \pi$ in both cases (ii) and (iii). The Legendre symbol $(\alpha /\pi)_3$ is then defined to be the unique cubic root of unity s.t. $\alpha^{\frac{N(\pi)-1}{3}}\equiv (\alpha /\pi)_3\pmod \pi$. The cyclicity of $(E/\pi E)^*$ implies that $(\alpha /\pi)_3=1$ iff $x^3\equiv \alpha \pmod \pi$ has a solution in $E$ .